# What is "Plate ID" and "Fiber"?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I have basic question. I found [publication](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.03031v1.pdf).

I'm interested in attachments - the last couple of pages in the document - Tables.

What are there Columns: "Plate ID" and "Fiber"?
Someone could give a definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically both Plate ID and Fiber are identifiers of the physical objects that took the data - plate as in "flat sheet of metal" and fiber as in "optic fiber".

The plates, which are round aluminum sheets with irregularly arranged mounting holes in them for the optic fiber heads, are used in the SDSS telescopes to take many spectra simultaneously.

Since the holes are aligned to correspond to the actual positions of the celestial objects - much like a star map done by drilling holes - they act like a bunch of apertures.

Additional information can be found on the [SDSSIII homepage](https://www.sdss3.org/dr9/spectro/spectro_basics.php) and this [hole drilling video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYyO7pGaJNw) is also quite interesting.